# How to save a text classification model and test it later on a new unseen data

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, text-classification, nlp

I am a newbie to python and working on a binary text classification problem. I have developed a text classification model. Now I want to save that trained model and reload it again to test it on a new test data file.

I tried pickle, and joblib for this task and some other suggested methods here at stack overflow but unable to do this. With one method, I successfully saved my model but couldn't test it on a new test data file. Any help shall be highly appreciated. Apologies if I couldn't explain the problem well as I am new to python.

```
Dataset = pd.read_csv('trainingdata.csv')
my_types = ['Requirement','Non-Requirement']


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(Dataset['description'],Dataset['types'],test_size=0.0, random_state=45)

tfidf_vect_ngram = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', 
token_pattern=r'\w{1,}', ngram_range=(1,1), max_features=5000)
tfidf_vect_ngram.fit(Dataset['description'])
X_train_Tfidf =  tfidf_vect_ngram.transform(X_train)

logreg = LogisticRegression(n_jobs=1, C=1e5)
logreg.fit(X_train_Tfidf, y_train)

import pickle
filename = 'finalized_model.sav'
pickle.dump(logreg, open(filename, 'wb'))

loaded_model = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))
result = loaded_model.score('testdata.csv')
print(result)
```

I also tried this one.

```
with open('text_classifier', 'wb') as picklefile:  
    pickle.dump(logreg,picklefile)

with open('text_classifier', 'rb') as training_model:  
    model = pickle.load(training_model)

result = model.predict('testdata.csv')
print(result)
```

One more solution I tried.

```
from keras.models import load_model

logreg.save('my_model.h5') 
del logreg

model = load_model('my_model.h5')
result=model('projectay.csv')
print(result)
```

Despite trying multiple solutions, I couldn't get the required results. I may be doing some blunder due to my less expertise in machine learning and python. May someone please point out where I am doing mistake. Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, The logistic regression model you have trained and saved, is fitted for for array of tfidf values. So why, after loading the model, are you predicting on a .csv file ? Shouldn't you first load the csv file with pandas and pass it through `tfidf_vect_ngram`, then pass the array/column to the loaded model ? So you need to save the `tfidf_vect_ngram` as well. Basically

```
X_test_tfidf = tfidf_vect_ngram.transform(X_test) # X_test can be the entire column if you are loading from a separate file
result = loaded_model.predict(X_test_tfidf)
score = loaded_model.score(X_test_tfidf, y_test)
```

If this not the issue, can you please post the error log/output as well instead of simply saying it doesn't work. That way we can figure out where exactly the problem is.